# Is there a way to automate downloading OHLC quotes for both tickers and fund codes from Yahoo Finance using Python?

Tags: download, finance, yahoo, price

I am trying to download a series of yesterday's Yahoo OHLC quotes for a portfolio of around 50 shares, trackers and ETFs. The share tickers work fine using the example code below, but the trackers and ETFs seem unobtainable by this method, even though I can find them manually using their Yahoo codes on the site.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()

start_date = (current_date - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = current_date
ticker_list = ["SHEL.L","BP.L" ]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for ticker in ticker_list:
  
    item = yf.download(ticker, start_date, end_date)
    df = pd.concat([df, item])
       
print(df.tail())
```

So far, so good, but when I try to use Yahoo's own code for an index fund, such as "0P0000TKZK.L" in place of the ticker list, I get an output as below:

1 Failed download:

- 0P0000TKZK.L: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]
  Index: []

I am not wedded to using yfinance; any other method which works for an automatic download of both tickers and the fund codes would be ideal. Any suggestions gratefully received.